# Artifactory Replication for Distributed Teams

Tags: npm, nuget, artifactory

My organization is in the process of deploying Artifactory for use by development teams in the US and India. Currently, the team in India experiences long delays because they're resolving dependencies from a server in the US; I'd like to improve this by mirroring the repo in India using Artifactory replication.

The replication documentation clearly states to "Avoid Replication Loops", i.e., A -> B and B -> A. That basically means that you can establish a chain, with the first server in the chain effectively being the "master", to which packages should be published for replication to all other servers. We'd be using the US server as the master.

Given this, how can we configure the repositories and/or developer workstations (for NPM and NuGet) such that the developers in India can resolve their dependencies from the server in India for faster development time, but still publish their artifacts to the server in the US so that replication will work correctly? Is it a matter of configuring the tools (npm/nuget) to pull from one place and push to another? Or is it possible to configure a virtual repository to pull locally and push remotely as described above, so that it's effectively transparent to the developers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so what you will need to do in order to make it work is the following:

In **USA** created the following repositories:

nuget-local

nuget-india-local

nuget-virtual --> Add the two nuget repositories to that virtual and set the nuget-local as the default deployment repo.
This is the repository that you give to your developers for both resolution and deployment.

npm-local

npm-india-local

npm-virtual --> Add the two npm repoitories to that virtual and set the npm-local as the default deployment repo.
This is the repository that you give to your developers for both resolution and deployment.

In **India** created the following repositories:

nuget-local

nuget-usa-local

nuget-virtual --> Add the two nuget repositories to that virtual and set the nuget-local as the default deployment repo.
This is the repository that you give to your developers for both resolution and deployment.

npm-local

npm-usa-local

npm-virtual --> Add the two npm repoitories to that virtual and set the npm-local as the default deployment repo.
This is the repository that you give to your developers for both resolution and deployment.

**Replication configuration:**

**USA:**

nuget-local --> set push replication (Local to local) to nuget-usa-local repository in India (I would suggest also on the event base replication)

npm-local --> set push replication (Local to local) to npm-usa-local repository in India (I would suggest also on the event base replication)

**India:**

nuget-local --> set push replication (Local to local) to nuget-india-local repository in India (I would suggest also on the event base replication)

npm-local --> set push replication (Local to local) to npm-india-local repository in India (I would suggest also on the event base replication)

This way you are avoiding the bi-directional limitation, and your teams will have the artifacts in the local instance.

**Relevant wiki links:**

[Push replication](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Repository+Replication#RepositoryReplication-PushReplication)

Comment: Thanks for all the info! Won't this configuration cause issues if both teams upload new versions of the same library? With one repo it will refuse unless the versions are different or they have overwrite permission, but I don't know if the setup you described offers the same protections.

Comment: The way that a virtual repository works it will aggregate the list of artifacts available on both the local and remote and will "return" one list to the client. In case that you asked for a specific version, it will try to first go to the local repo and fetch from there.